# How to take out functions from the render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am making a basic page which displays all details to the user using a map function. 
However I have been advised by other developers to take out my functions from the render method. 
I understand why it is bad (constantly renders things I do not need to re render).

I am just a little bit stuck with the syntax of remodeling this.
Here is my code.

```
import React from "react";

import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { Modal, DropdownButton, Dropdown } from "react-bootstrap";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

var results = [];
class AdminWorkstations extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      questions: [],
      viewDetails: false,

      currentPage: 1,
      todosPerPage: 4
    };
    this.getQuestionByUniqueDate = this.getQuestionByUniqueDate.bind(this);
    // this.test = this.test.bind(this);
  }
  // sets the questions form sql into state for questions
  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`/admin-completed-workstations`)
      .then(recordset => recordset.json())
      .then(results => {
        this.setState({ questions: results.recordset });
        console.log(this.state.questions);

        this.state.questions &&
          this.getQuestionByUniqueDate(this.state.questions);
      });
  }

  handlePageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({ activePage: pageNumber });
  }

  getQuestionByUniqueDate(questions) {
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      if (
        !results.find(q => q.Date == questions[i].Date) ||
        !results.find(
          q => q.AssignedWorkStation == questions[i].AssignedWorkStation
        )
      ) {
        results.push(questions[i]);
        this.setState({ amountOfWorkstations: results.length });
      }
    }
    return results;
  }

  render() {
    const { currentPage, todosPerPage } = this.state;

    // can these be moved to state? 
    const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
    const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
// can this be moved out of render and how? 
    const pageNumbers = [];
    for (
      let i = 1;
      i <= Math.ceil(this.state.amountOfWorkstations / todosPerPage);
      i++
    ) {
      pageNumbers.push(i);
    }
// can this be moved out of render and how ? 
    const renderTodos = currentTodos.map(r => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="jumbotron">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" style={{ float: "right" }}>
              View Details
            </button>

            <br />
            <li>
              <b>Workstation : </b>

              {r.AssignedWorkStation}
            </li>
            <li>
              <b>Date: </b>
              {r.Date}
            </li>

            <li>
              <b>Status: </b>
              {r.CompleteToken}
            </li>

            <br />
            {/* <Questions results={r}></Questions> */}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    });
// can this be moved out of render ans how ? 
    const renderPageNumbers = pageNumbers.map(number => {
      return (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          key={number}
          id={number}
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          {number}
        </button>
      );
    });

    let selectedWorkStation = window.localStorage.getItem("Workstation");

    console.log(this.state.questions);

    if (this.state.questions.length) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            Completed Workstation Assessments
          </h2>
          <ul>
            <button disabled className="btn btn-secondary">
              Workstation Assessments
            </button>
            <Link to="./admin-center">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">Edit Questions</button>
            </Link>
            <Link to="./admin-center-view-users">
              <button className="btn btn-secondary">View Users</button>
            </Link>
            <DropdownButton
              style={{ float: "right" }}
              id="dropdown-basic-button"
              title="Completed"
            >
              <Dropdown.Item>
                {" "}
                <Link to="admin-view-workstation-assessments-declined">
                  In Progress
                </Link>
              </Dropdown.Item>
            </DropdownButton>{" "}
          </ul>

          <ul>
            {renderTodos}{" "}
            <div
              style={{ userSelect: "none", cursor: "pointer" }}
              id="page-numbers"
            >
              {renderPageNumbers}
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    } else if (!this.state.questions.length) {
      return (
        <>
          {" "}
          <div>
            <h3 style={{ textAlign: "center" }}></h3>

            <ul>
              <br />
              <br />{" "}
              <div>
                <h6>
                  {" "}
                  <tr>
                    Desk Location Selected :{" "}
                    <u style={{ color: "grey" }}>{selectedWorkStation}</u>
                  </tr>
                </h6>
              </div>
              <div className="jumbotron">
                <li style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                  <b>no completed Workstation Self-Assessments</b>{" "}
                </li>
              </div>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I still want everything to behave the same. But I have noticed that my navigation buttons do not appear sometimes upon navigation to the screen and I am fairly sure this is why without a refresh .
I have put brief comments where some of these are . 
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Largely by cutting-and-pasting. You can either take out the function, or create a new component that takes number and click handler props. What's the *specific* confusion?

Comment: I have been recommended to take the rendertodos out of the render but I have no idea how I would then return the information they it is returning

Comment: The same way you are now--your `map` call returns an array of fragments, so would your function.

Answer (score 0):

So beginning with:

```
const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);
```

As I can see only **currentTodos** is being actually used for **renderTodos** it can definitely be moved `state` in the following function as:

```
handleClick = event => {
  const indexOfLastTodo = currentPage * todosPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstTodo = indexOfLastTodo - todosPerPage;
  const currentTodos = results.slice(indexOfFirstTodo, indexOfLastTodo);

  this.setState({
    currentPage: Number(event.target.id),
    currentTodos,
  });
};
```

Now, coming to **renderTodos**, it can be made as a functional component in some other file as:

```
const renderTodos = ({ currentTodos }) => {
    currentTodos.map(r => (
        <div className="jumbotron">
            <button
               className="btn btn-primary"
               style={{ float: 'right' }}
             >
                View Details
            </button>

            <br />
            <li>
                <b>Workstation : </b>
                {r.AssignedWorkStation}
            </li>

            <li>
                <b>Date: </b>
                {r.Date}
            </li>

            <li>
                <b>Status: </b>
                {r.CompleteToken}
            </li>
            <br />
        </div>
    ));
};
```

and then can be imported from that file as: `import RenderTodos from './renderTodos';` and can be used in your **render()** method as a **JSX element**: `<RenderTodos currentTodos={currentTodos}/>`

Same way you can extract **renderPageNumbers** as a functional component and use it in your render method, plus don't forget to pass the `pageNumbers` prop.